# C# Form Application on click event

Tags: c#

Please help me to fix this problem in c#. Every time i accidentally click any Button,Text Box etc. it will go to the source code and when i delete the code, debug wont run, but when i put comment sign `/* comment*/` the application will run.

Any one can help me on how to remove on click event.

**this is what i want to remove**

```
 private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

 { }
```

Every time i delete this debug will prompt me. but when i using VB i can easily delete this no need to remove the button or txtbox etc.

Comment: What is the prompt? Maybe you need to delete the event handler as well on designer code.

Comment: got it bro.. thanks man, hehe was used to VB where u can directly delete the code hahaha but in c# it bit different haha

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it deletes automatically sometimes its not, so just double check it always.

Answer (score 2):

Basically when you double click a control, the designer automatically create a the event handler.

It also automatically assigns the event handler to the control. It makes this change in the designer.cs file of your form. This is handeled for you.

Unfortunately,  when you remove the code you pointed out, the function no longer exists. Therefore,  the solutions fails to build because the reference to the function still exist in the. Designer.cs file.

You need to remove the reference in the designer.cs file:

"If you click on a control in the Form Designer, you see a list of event handlers that the designer is associating with the control in the Properties Window.  Click on the lightning bolt at the top of the Window to see a listing of events.  You will see method names next to events that the Form Designer is writing code for in the designer.cs file.  Simply erase the name of the method for the event you wish to disconnect, hit Enter, done."
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a6f25488-b761-437f-8a65-e7e51dd4b382/remove-event-handler?forum=csharpgeneral

You would not have to do this in VB.net, as VB.net uses the `handles` command whereas c# performs a method like so: 
`button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);`

Comment: Yes, it works bro. hahaha cool now i know how to fix issue hahaha yeah in VB u can easily highlight and delete the code. but anyway thanks man, appreciate your help..

Comment: Please mark the solution as answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply remove the event from your element before deleting the method in your code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There will be a line in form.designer.cs class just remove that.
comboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged+=new eventargs(comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged);

Moreover, windows forms use CodDom to write a code to you have to be careful hope this will help you to learn more about creating windows form application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-controls-to-windows-forms